# Document library refinement

Tags: document-library, refinement-panel

I am aware that I can use the filters on each column in a document library, but some of my users are asking if they can have refinement options on the page similar to the search experience.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you have taxonomy associated with items or documents in the List or Library, then you can use OOTB Taxonomy filter box in Left-Side Panel  i.e.
http://manojmittalblogs.blogspot.in/2015/05/filter-based-onmanaged-metadata-using.html

Comment: Please include details in your answer instead of linking to a blog. That link may break, leaving your answer less helpful than it could be